# php html comment missing

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Ok I am missing something stooped most probably...

I have this code in my Wordpres:

```
echo "<!-- ";
echo  get_home_url();
echo  ' -->';
echo "After";
```

This is allready simplimentation of the original code, but the problem is that when I am looking at te ROW output all I have is:

view-source:http://nes-jewelry.com/?____icl_validate_domain=1&w3tc_note=flush_all

After

The comment is missing!!!!
This is a nginx+fpm_php+wordpress

And the plugin in work is WPML

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like W3TC is removing comments.

edit: the W3TC FAQ proves that: http://www.w3-edge.com/products/w3-total-cache/ ("What's the benefit of removing HTML comments from my code?")

Comment: Thank you... That is defenetly important data!